# Exit code of job launched by bsub

Tags: c++, lsf

Is there a way to collect the exit code of a job launched by bsub?

For example: There is a script test.sh (test.sh contains a few binaries that gets launched after one another) that is launched by bsub.

```
std::string cmdLine = "bsub test.sh";
File *fp = popen(cmdLine.c_str());
int retcode = pclose(fp); // this returns exit code of bsub (not wanted in this scenario)
```

I am looking for a way to get exit codes of binaries launched by bsub?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LSF is a batch scheduling system and as such your interaction with it as a client is asynchronous:

1. you submit your job for scheduling using bsub, the bsub command
   returns immediately
2. List item in the background, the system schedules and
   dispatches your job

To find the status of the actual workload, I can give you a couple of options.

**Option 1**

Force `bsub` to act synchronously.  This is probably the easiest option given the current state of the code sample: basically all you have to do is give `bsub` the `-K` option.  This causes the command to essentially not return until the job has been queued, dispatched, and completed, and then the command will return the exit code of the job just like you want:

```
std::string cmdLine = "bsub -K test.sh";  // Use -K option
File *fp = popen(cmdLine.c_str());
int retcode = pclose(fp);  // this will now return the exit code of test.sh
```

**Option 2**

Some sites don't like letting users use the `-K` option for various reasons.  If that's the case for you, then you'll need to query the system for the status of your job using the `bjobs` command.

Basically, after `bsub` returns, your code will just repeatedly call the `bjobs` command and parse the output in order to determine the exit status of your job.  For example:

```
$ bjobs -o 'stat exit_code' 6308
STAT EXIT_CODE
DONE -
```

Gives me the columns for exit status and exit code for job ID 6308 (the job ID is obtained by parsing the output of `bsub` when submitting your jobs):

- If the status column is `DONE` your job completed successfully
- If the status column is `EXIT` then your job ended abnormally and you can get the exit code from the EXIT_CODE column
- If the status column is `RUN` or `PEND` then your job is running or waiting for dispatch respectively, your code should `sleep()` for little while and try to call `bjobs` again.

Note that the example `bjobs` output above uses the `-o` option to customize the output for easy parsing.  That's a relatively new feature, if you're using an older version of LSF you'll have to make do without it -- doable, but a bit more involved.